# Magento fatal error adding swatches to custom theme

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add swatches to my custom theme, but after I copy files from rwd theme, I get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductAttribute() on a
>   non-object in
>   /app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml
>   on line 38

Comment: did you check line no 38 in swatches.phtml

Comment: here it is $_attr = $_attribute->getProductAttribute();

Comment: did you copy all files of extension in your theme?

Comment: yes, i am using this guide http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a

Comment: download your extension and check it's file structure then copy them at right place  you can download extension by pasting it's key here http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Comment: which magento version you have used?

Comment: what extension are we talking about? swatches are already included in 1.9, I would like to just make it work with a custom theme

Comment: then read this original tutorial and follow its step carefully   https://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/

Comment: I've read that guide too, but same error, any clue?